# python pandas reshape - time series table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

i need to reshape the time series table

ex) A => B

A

```
no,A,B,B_sub
1,start,val_s,val_s_sub
2,study,val_st,val_st_sub
3,work,val_w,val_w_sub
4,end,val_e,val_e_sub
5,start,val_s1,val_s1_sub
6,end,val_e1,val_e1_sub
7,start,val_s2,val_s2_sub
8,work,val_w1,val_w1_sub
9,end,val_e2,val_e2_sub
```

B

```
,start,,study,,work,,end,
,B,B_sub,B,B_sub,B,B_sub,B,B_sub
4-1,val_s,val_s_sub,val_st,val_st_sub,val_w,val_w_sub,val_e,val_e_sub
6-5,val_s1,val_s1_sub,,,,,val_e1,val_e1_sub
9-7,val_s2,val_s2_sub,,,val_w1,val_w1_sub,val_e2,val_e2_sub
```

I tried to use the pivot table function of the python - pandas library,
but there is no common string to use as index in my table

can i get a hint?

i'm lost.. help me plz..

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this get you close enough?

```
df_a['grp'] = (df_a['A'] == 'start').cumsum()
df_a.set_index(['grp','A']).unstack('A')
```

Output:

```
      no                        B                               B_sub                                    
A    end start study work     end   start   study    work         end       start       study        work
grp                                                                                                      
1    4.0   1.0   2.0  3.0   val_e   val_s  val_st   val_w   val_e_sub   val_s_sub  val_st_sub   val_w_sub
2    6.0   5.0   NaN  NaN  val_e1  val_s1     NaN     NaN  val_e1_sub  val_s1_sub         NaN         NaN
3    9.0   7.0   NaN  8.0  val_e2  val_s2     NaN  val_w1  val_e2_sub  val_s2_sub         NaN  val_w1_sub
```

Going a little further with reshaping and renaming and shaping:

```
df_r = df_a.set_index(['grp','A']).unstack('A')

steps = df_r[('no', 'end')].astype(int).astype(str).str.cat(df_r[('no', 'start')].astype(int).astype(str), sep='-')

df_r.set_index(steps)[['B', 'B_sub']].swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
A             end               start               study                work            
                B       B_sub       B       B_sub       B       B_sub       B       B_sub
(no, end)                                                                                
4-1         val_e   val_e_sub   val_s   val_s_sub  val_st  val_st_sub   val_w   val_w_sub
6-5        val_e1  val_e1_sub  val_s1  val_s1_sub     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
9-7        val_e2  val_e2_sub  val_s2  val_s2_sub     NaN         NaN  val_w1  val_w1_sub
```

Comment: thank you so much !!
thanks to you, I got to know a new function, 'cumsum()'. ( this was the key to the answer ! )
I expect to analyze massive log files more easily.

Comment: @INHEE Thank you!  I am glad to share.   Be safe and stay healthy!